# EF Core Unique Constraint across multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-framework-core

How do I create/design the relationship and unique constraint:

A PROJECT has many SUBJOBS. A SUBJOB has many TASKS. A TASK has a Number which must be unique across a single PROJECT.

I tried the following for the relationship but I can't figure out how to enforce the unique constraint for `Task.Number` and `Project.ProjectId`:

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Project { get; private set; }

    public DbSet<SubJob> SubJob { get; private set; }

    public DbSet<Task> Task { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(p => p.ProjectId);
            b.HasAlternateKey(p => p.Code);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubJob>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(s => s.SubJobId);
            b.HasOne(s => s.Project).WithMany(p => p.SubJobs).HasForeignKey(s => s.ProjectId);
            b.HasAlternateKey(s => new { s.ProjectId, s.Code });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(l => l.TaskId);
            b.HasOne(l => l.SubJob).WithMany(s => s.Tasks).HasForeignKey(l => l.SubJobId);
        });
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; private set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubJob> SubJobs { get; private set; } = new List<SubJob>();
}

public class SubJob
{
    public int SubJobId { get; private set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; private set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; private set; } = new List<Task>();
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; private set; }

    public int SubJobId { get; private set; }

    public SubJob SubJob { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities. Use natural keys for the child classes, so Subjob might be {ProjectId, JobCode} and Task might be {ProjectId, JobCode, Number}. But if the {ProjectId, Number} must be unique, then that would be the PK and JobCode would be a non-null FK, but not part of the PK.

Or, if your database supports indexed views you could create a view with a unique index on {ProjectId, Number}.

Answer (score 0):

To define unique constraint on `Tasks` table, you would need to get value of `ProjectId` in `Task` class. The modified `Task` entity would look like this.

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; private set; }
    public int SubJobId { get; private set; }
    public SubJob SubJob { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; } // Added property
}
```

Since every `Task` has a `SubJob` and every `SubJob` has a `Project`, `Task.ProjectId` should be equal to `Task.SubJob.ProjectId` (which in turn takes value from `SubJob.Project.ProjectId`). To make sure this value is passed around we can define a relationship between `Task` & `SubJob` to use composite keys like following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(l => l.TaskId);
    b.HasOne(l => l.SubJob).WithMany(s => s.Tasks).HasForeignKey(l => new { l.SubJobId, l.ProjectId })
        .HasPrincipalKey(l => new { l.SubJobId, l.ProjectId });
    b.HasAlternateKey(t => new { t.Number, t.ProjectId });
});
```

Then we can define the unique constraint over `Number` & `ProjectId` using `HasAlternateKey`.

You could also use Composite Keys with `ProjectId` as being part but that could require to setup value generation for other part of PK.

Unless you really need unique constraint, consider using unique index. More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys)

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve this is creating a foreign key in `Task` class referencing `Project` and then create a unique index that forces the uniqueness.

Task class would have this extra property:

`public int ProjectId { get; private set; }`

And your DbContext would look like this (when using FluentAPI):

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .HasOne<Project>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .HasIndex(t => new { t.Number., t.ProjectId})
                .IsUnique();
```

PS: Depending on your other relationships, you might need to change your deleting behavior to avoid cycles.